# How do I check if two types have the same bit pattern and type?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have 3 types, `A` and `B` and `int`. I want to know if some combination of instantiations of these types have the same content of bits. I know nothing about what `A` or `B` actually contain, and I don't care. I just want to know if they're the same type and have the same bit pattern.

For example:

```
struct A { int a{2}; };
struct B
{
  B()
  {
    int x = 2;
    b = *reinterpret_cast<double*>(&i);
  }
  double b;
}

template <typename T1, typename T2>
bool IsSame(const T1& t1, const T2& t2)
{
  return t1 == t2; // this won't work... No '==' operator!
};

int main()
{
  A a;
  B b;
  A a2;
  a2.a = 1;

  int c = 2;

  IsSame(a, a); // this will be true
  IsSame(a, b); // this will be false even though a and b probably have the same bit pattern.
  IsSame(a, a2); // false because a2 contains a "2"
  IsSame(a, c); // false because they're different types
}
```

How do I implement `IsSame`?

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is not a library function within `std`, it's a language-provided cast, and it's the wrong choice of cast for `int -> double`.

Comment: So you basically want to see if some areas of memory have the same bit pattern?

Comment: Do you mean that you want a literal bitwise comparison?  This isn't a well-defined problem (other than for primitives, I suppose), because of issues like padding.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth yes that's exactly what I want.

Comment: @chris I don't think you've understood the question. If something is unclear please let me know.

Comment: @qaunt in C/C++ everything can be a char* if you want it to be and do what is essentially a byte array comparison. Padding and the such will be a pain in your side though.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<double>(2)` is an invalid expression. Perhaps you wanted `static_cast` (or no cast, as the implicit cast is well defined as long as you don't use the braces).

Comment: @user657267: I'm pretty sure the OP does want a reinterpret; he wants a `double` that contains the same bit pattern as the `int`, not the same value.

Comment: Well, `reinterpret_cast` is still not a member of any namespace, and it still only converts to pointers and references. Perhaps something like `int * -> double *` was desired.

Comment: Yeah I want to reinterpret, but user657267 is right, it's invalid.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? I doubt it will be portable.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth In that case he needs to use `*reinterpret_cast<double*>` with an int pointer.

Comment: @NeilKirk, basically I want to compare equality for POD types without knowing if they're the same type or not, and whether or not the `==` operator is overloaded. This is the easiest way, and I can eliminate false positives by adding a `std::is_same` check.

Comment: Yes but why do you want to do that? C++ is built around types.

Comment: @quant Universal Equality is achieved in most languages by a single supertype like Object in C# or Java. Doing something like this in C++ is not idiomatic and is asking for pain down the road. If you have your own types you want to have universal equality over you can introduce your own supertype for them.

Comment: @NeilKirk debugging functionality for a DSL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if two objects have identical representation you can write:

```
if ( 0 == std::memcmp(&t1, &t2, sizeof t1) )
```

Be aware that some of the bits of an object may not participate in its value representation; and/or there may be multiple possible representations for the same value; so objects that would compare equal via `operator==` may appear unequal using this method.

You should also add in a check that `sizeof t1 == sizeof t2`, this can be done at compile-time.

Comment: Shouldn't that be std::memcmp(&t1, &t2, min(sizeof t1, sizeof t2)) or max?  Not just the size of the first type?

Comment: @MorphingDragon You should check that the sizes are identical first.

Comment: Actually, for this to work, the objects need to be [Trivially Copyable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TriviallyCopyable), do they not?

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod don't think so. `memcmp` is specified as being the same as C99, and in C99 it compares character by character; and it's permitted in C++ to alias any type as a character type

Comment: Of course the result is not very meaningful since any struct may contain padding